# Python oop: __init__ methods of class have often trivial assignments self.value=value

Tags: python, oop

Often python classes have following form of `__init__` methods:

```
class myclass:
     def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

The trivial assignment of method parameter and instance variable feels like unnecessary code. As far as I understand, following does not work:

```
class myclass:
     def __init__(self, self.value):
        pass
```

and I always have to write `__init__` methods with these trivial assignments.

Is this correct?

Comment: Whats trivial about it? You're defining a class..

Comment: I believe it is part of Python's ethos that explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the following for many years now:

```
def MyClass:
    def __init__(self, some_var, some_other_var, some_kwarg=None):
        self.__dict__.update(locals())
```

To me, this clearly shows that I want to declare all the variables passed to `__init__` to be instance variables, but it might not be so for someone unfamiliar with Python's classes, so use it warily.

What it does, essentially, is to push all local--scope variables to the instance's variable dictionary. You can even combine it with `**kwargs` (using Python 3.5 syntax):

```
def MyClass:
    def __init__(self, some_var, some_other_var, some_kwarg=None, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update({**locals(), **kwargs})
```

to allow arbitrary keyword arguments to be pushed into the instance's variable scope, though I highly discourage this usage for most purposes.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just performing an assignment; it's also essentially doubling as the "declaration" of your instance variables. Yes, there's nothing stopping you from adding more instance variables at any time during the life of the object, but by convention, the attributes you assign to in `__init__` provide the *de facto* definition of what attributes are available on an instance of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct: you must always do these assignments inside `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

In general - yes. Python cannot know what you want to do with the arguments given to `__init__` inside `__init__` unless you tell it.

Depending on what you want your class to do, you *could* play with keyword arguments and setattr.

```
>>> class AutoSetter(object):
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...         for x in kwargs:
...             setattr(self, x, kwargs[x])
...
>>> a = AutoSetter(value1=42, value2=23, foo=0)
>>> a.value1
42
>>> a.value2
23
>>> a.foo
0
```

Comment: I like your proposal of `**kwargs`. However, I think the answer of Chepner makes the right point:  it's not only an assignment but also a declaration. In your code names of instance variables are declared outside of the class. That's usually not what I want. So both answers helped me to better understand this aspect.

Comment: @Hotschke I agree with the answer by chepner. The AutoSetter class is just a quirky example of what you could do.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have anything else in the class, you could try [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
myclass = namedtuple('myclass', ['value'])
```